# How can I create a second working model for another button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, dialog, modal-dialog

I am currently creating a page where you can click on images, and then a modal should appear. Now the problem: the second modal does not appear.
I've tried many things but nothing worked

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const openModal = document.querySelector('.open-button');
const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-button');

openModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.showModal();
})

closeModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.close();
})
```

```html
<button class="open-button"> 
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" alt="">
</button>

<dialog class="modal">
  <button class="close-button">close it</button>
</dialog>

<!-- second modal -->
<button class="open-button"> 
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" alt="">
</button>

<dialog class="modal">
  <button class="close-button">close it</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: One way would be to use `data`-attribute. The other method would be to use the `closest()` function in  JS. With `querySelector` you only return the first matching element.

Comment: The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll